# Saving a dictionary with string keys and bytes values to file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, credentials

I am writing a python program which should be able to run on Windows, iOS and Android.

To handle logins in I have a `dict` `{key_string: hashed_password_bytes}` Currently I manually convert any strings to binary and concatenate them all into a binary string I parse when loading credentials from file. Once it's in a readable binary format file I/O is pretty trivial

The code is pretty lengthy (below). **Does anyone know of a package which can write dictionaries to file, not using clear text, that does the same job?**

Packages I have tried but couldn't find a suitable method of using them

- Pickle. Dropped due to the code injection risk https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html
- YAML, JSON etc as I don't want to use clear text solutions for storing credentials.
- Struct requires that you know the length of variables and string variables before opening.
- Netstruct allows variable length strings however you I couldn't figure out how to unpack dictionaries into it or the required format string to return an unknown number of a mixture of strings and bytes variables.
- Pyvault would take the pain out of this task but unfortunately it requires sqlcipher and I don't want to install that on every device that the program runs on.

Current solution (print calls will obviously be removed after a healthy amount of debugging):

```
import scrypt
import os

MAX_TIME = 0.5  # Set here for ease of changing
FILE_001_DAT_LOCATION = "Source/001.dat"
DATA_LENGTH = 64  # Data length for hashing password
ENCODING_STRING = 'utf-8'  # Used in all string encode and decode
PACKING_SIZE_STRING_LENGTH = 4  # The number of bytes used by the size indicator for the proceeding username/password
SIZE_STRING_FORMAT = '{:0>4}'  # Used to format the size integer for packing dictionaries


# Turns {string: bytes} into bytes for writing to file
# Format is username1size, username1, password1size, password1, username2size...
def pack_credentials(credentials: dict):
    bytes_out = b""

    print("pack_credentials() called. Starting loop")

    # Loop over every key and add keys
    for key in credentials.keys():
        # Pack username
        print(f"Encoding username: {key}")
        encoded_username = key.encode(ENCODING_STRING)
        username_size = len(encoded_username)
        print(f"Encoded username has size: {username_size}")
        username_size_string = SIZE_STRING_FORMAT.format(username_size)
        bytes_out += username_size_string.encode(ENCODING_STRING) + encoded_username

        # Pack hashed password
        print(f"Encoding password: {str(credentials[key])}")
        password_size = len(credentials[key])
        print(f"Hashed password has size: {password_size}")
        password_size_string = SIZE_STRING_FORMAT.format(password_size)
        bytes_out += password_size_string.encode(ENCODING_STRING) + credentials[key]

    print("Packing complete. Returning bytes.")
    return bytes_out


# Hash a raw password and return - for adding new credentials to the dictionary
def hash_password(password):
    return scrypt.encrypt(os.urandom(DATA_LENGTH), password, maxtime=MAX_TIME)


# Turns {string: bytes} into bytes for writing to file
# Format is username1size, username1, password1size, password1, username2size...
def unpack_credentials(bytes_in: bytes):
    credentials_out = {}  # Defined here to add to in loop
    slice_start = 0  # Starting index for next slice from bytes_in
    slice_end = slice_start + PACKING_SIZE_STRING_LENGTH  # Ending index for next slice from bytes_in
    bytes_in_length = len(bytes_in)

    print("unpack_credentials() called. Starting loop")

    # Loop over every key and add keys
    while slice_end < bytes_in_length:
        # Unpack username
        print(f"Unpacking username size")
        username_length_bytes = bytes_in[slice_start:slice_end]
        print(f"Username size: {username_length_bytes}")
        print(f"Unpacking username")
        slice_start = slice_end
        slice_end = slice_end + int(username_length_bytes.decode(ENCODING_STRING))
        username_bytes = bytes_in[slice_start:slice_end]
        print(f"Username: {username_bytes.decode(ENCODING_STRING)}")

        # Pack hashed password
        print(f"Unpacking password size")
        slice_start = slice_end
        slice_end = slice_end + PACKING_SIZE_STRING_LENGTH
        password_length_bytes = bytes_in[slice_start:slice_end]
        print(f"Password size: {password_length_bytes.decode(ENCODING_STRING)}")
        slice_start = slice_end
        slice_end = slice_end + int(password_length_bytes.decode(ENCODING_STRING))
        print(f"Unpacking password")
        password_bytes = bytes_in[slice_start:slice_end]

        #Prepare for next iteration
        slice_start = slice_end
        slice_end = slice_end + PACKING_SIZE_STRING_LENGTH


        #Populate dict
        credentials_out[username_bytes.decode(ENCODING_STRING)] = password_bytes

    print("Unpacking complete. Returning dict.")
    return credentials_out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # appGUI = MyApp()
    # appGUI.run()

    original_credentials = {"User 1 boiiiiiii": hash_password("password1wEDFRAwerwq rq"),
                   "Sonic the hedgehog": hash_password("password2qwergasdfghwerterwqgdfsg"),
                   "Misty water colour memories": hash_password("password3qdaserfgwqeryhger5wtywrthsfdghsd"),
                   "Niko the big black dog": hash_password("password4eadgrasewrdgerwqttgeqrwtgdfgewrtyertertgeertet")}

    credentials_binary = pack_credentials(original_credentials)
    new_credentials = unpack_credentials(credentials_binary)
    print(
        f"Do password hashes match? {original_credentials['User 1 boiiiiiii'] == new_credentials['User 1 boiiiiiii']}")
```

Comment: What exactly do you have against "clear text", and isn't your own format pretty much clear text?

Comment: Please, check [help/on-topic]

Comment: Reading the question again, this looks like XY problem. Do you actually ask how to store hashed (and I hope also salted) passwords in a DB/file?

Comment: `json` + `zip` ?

Comment: @KellyBundy - I guess it just feels wrong to put cached usernames into a JSON file. The packed bytes string is arbitrarily changed so that it isn't read as clear text when saved to file.

Comment: @buran, I'd hoped this has a bit of source code regarding a specific programming problem (storing string/bytes dict), asking if a software tool commonly used by programmers does the same job, is practical (I'm using a version of it), answerable problem that is unique to software development... Also, password has whatever Scrypt does. I believed that it's salted then hashed but it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: I don't think you're adding security with that format of yours, you're just making it inconvenient for yourself.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, json and encrypted zip sounds perfect, thanks!!!